# Redirect www to non-www and prevent 301 for 404 Errorpage

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have problems with htaccess and hope that someone can help me:
I have a wordpress installation in the `/wordpress` directory. So if someone accesses "www.mysite.com" or "mysite.com" I want to redirect to `/wordpress` .

I *had* on the server some sites like `/deleted.html`
So I added a 404-Errorpage: `ErrorDocument 404 /wordpress/404.php` .
Everything works properly for the 404-page if you access `mysite.com/deleted.html` but not if you access `www.mysite.com/deleted.html`.
In this case there is at first a 301 Redirect and then the 404 page is loaded. This is a problem for Google because they can't detect the page as deleted.
This is how it looks like:

```
curl -I -L http://www.mysite.com/deleted.html

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Tue, 24 Sep 2013 16:02:18 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.25 (Unix)
Location: http://mysite.com/deleted.html
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Tue, 24 Sep 2013 16:02:18 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.25 (Unix)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Pragma: no-cache
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge,chrome=1
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

This is my .htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 /wordpress/404.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wordpress 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.net$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wordpress
```

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: That is because of `permalink` setting in WP. Better to always redirect everything to WP configured `http://mysite.com` first.

Comment: You're right. The permalink setting is the issue. I solved it for now by creating a static html file for the Errorpage with a meta redirection to my wordpress 404-page. 

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://mysite.com/wordpress/404.php">` 
But now the user gets to see for a second the static page and then the redirection happens. So to do it properly I need to solve the permalink issue..

Comment: That is more like a hack solution. Let me suggest you something in my answer, use it if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in your .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /wordpress/404.php

RewriteEngine On

# first redirect everything to http://mysite.com/net, recognized by WP permalink
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(mysite\.(?:net|com))$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# forward everything to wordpress folder
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.(com|net)$
RewriteRule ^$ wordpress [L]
```

Comment: With my solution using meta redirection `mysite.com/deleted.html`, `www.mysite.com/deleted.html`, `mysite.com/wordpress/deleted.html` returns only 404, but for `www.mysite.com/wordpress/deleted.html` I get at first 301 and then 404

Comment: With above rules in place as suggested `www.mysite.com/wordpress/deleted.html` will be redirected to `mysite.com/wordpress/deleted.html` first (301) and then 404 will be handled by `/wordpress/404.php`. There will be no need of `deleted.html`

Comment: Just to make clear. `deleted.html` is a file that was deleted. It doesn't exist on the server so a 404 page should be shown. The problem is that if e.g. Google checks if `www.mysite.com/wordpress/deleted.html` exists, the server will return at first 301 and later 404 as shown in the output of curl. So Google will still think that the file exists although it is deleted. This is the reason why I want to avoid a redirect from www. to non-www if the file doesn't exist.

Comment: If any search bot get 404 it will not think that file exists (301 is irrelevant here)

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the case. If I use "Fetch as Google" in Webmaster Tools it returns a "success" for a non-existent url. e.g. `http://www.mysite.com/noexistent000.html` with your htaccess but with my solution using meta redirection it shows  "Not found".

Comment: If it is returning "success" that means solution wasn't implemented completely. Anyway you know what is best for your requirements.

Comment: It is a little strange. I used "Remove URLs" in Webmaster Tools and it didn't let me do that saying that the page still exists. But now it doesn't say that. Still it shows success if I use "Fetch as Google". I will leave the meta redirection to make 100% sure it will work and later I will think about using your solution.

Comment: I will mark your answer as accepted, especially because you pointed me to the permalink-issue. I didn't know about that. So thanks for your help. :)